# Add contents to a WebView's HTML

Tags: javascript, cocoa, webkit

I want to add HTML contents to the end of the document. It's loaded to a WebKit via local or remote URL:

```
[[myWebView mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
```

How to add the text there? The convenient document.write() does work but erases all the previously loaded HTML contents:

```
[myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.write('Hello!')"];
```

Interesting: it erases only once. The following document.write()s work correctly, not erasing the existing Hello's.

Also, I tried another JS: `document.getElementById('end_div').innerHTML += something` - it does the job, but reloads the div contents. If the div has Youtube `<iframe>s`, they are all reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Did it via jQuery:

```
jQuery('<div/>', {
    html: my_text
}).appendTo('body');
```

But I still hope there is a way to make `document.write()` work as expected...